# I need my Chrome Extension to check for an updated JSON file daily

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've built a Chrome Extension for my team that allows users to pull down and sync a list of bookmarks stored as a JSON document located in an S3 Bucket. I've already added functionality for users to click a "Check for updates" button which compares an updated date in the JSON file to a stored date in the users browser. This works perfectly. As always, users want more and I was asked that the extension checks to see if the browser has the latest bookmarks and automatically pulls down the latest JSON data if it does not.

- Is there away to have the extension check daily for a newer version of the JSON file?
- What event would I wire into to trigger this new check?
- It does not have to be daily and could be based on any event so other options are fine

Thank you very much for any advice!

Comment: See `chrome.alarms`.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm That is what I was looking for!!!